# LaTeX3 output routine

Tags: latex3, output-routine

In the source and documentation of the `dblfloatfix` package there is a line that states

> When the new output routine for LATEX3 is done, this package will be obsolete.The sooner the better...

Are there any resources on what changes are planned to LaTeX3's output routine, particularily on how the mechanism that places floats in multi-column layouts will work?

Comment: You can browse the code for the new output routine: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/master/xpackages/xor

Comment: Is the float placement concept described in https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/xpackages/xor/xo-pfloat.pdf still valid?

Comment: I would think so, assuming that you can actually get `xor` to work in your document (which is pretty unlikely because it's incompatible with just about everything else).